# Injecting additional values after initial bean initialization

Tags: spring

I have a situation where a bean is originally defined by a project to be used in a specific runtime environment.  However, this project is also used in a different runtime environment that would either

- like to redefine a specific bean
- or (better) inject some additional values into the already initialized bean.

I hate overwriting beans, can get very confusing, so I want to try the second option.

A more concrete example:

base.xml might include

```
<bean id="xxx" class="yyy">
  <constructor-arg>
    <map>
      <entry key="key1" value="val1"/>
    </map>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This bean is used all over the place in project A.

Project B uses project A, loads all its spring configuration, but needs to add
another value to the bean's map.

Something like.. I dunno

```
<bean id="xxx1" class="yyy" parent="xxx">
  <property name="additionalMapValues">
    <map>
      <entry key="key1" value="val1"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Don't really care about the new bean, I want to affect the original bean.  Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out abstract bean definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just additional map properties (or other collection properties) that you need in the new bean, you can use Spring's collection merging functionality. For example - similar to what you'd already shown, project A might declare:

```
<bean id="xxx" class="yyy">
    <property name="mapValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="key1" value="val1"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then in project B, you can create a new bean definition that extends this - and merge in any new properties using the `merge="true"` attribute.

```
<bean id="xxx1" parent="xxx">
    <property name="mapValues">
        <map merge="true">
            <entry key="key2" value="val2"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that both beans would be concrete in this case. So parent bean `xxx` would only include `key1` whereas child bean `xxx1` would just include both `key1` and `key2`.

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-merging) and another example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_collection_merging_spring)

Comment: Interesting! That's a good trick to know. But sadly, I need 'xxx' to have the new property.  I really don't even want a new bean, which makes me think not doing this correctly.  I just need to add a property to an existing bean that is used all over (both project A and B).